# Is there a way to check for instructions in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm

Is there any method to check of an IR is load, store,branch or add etc in llvm

```
%1 = alloca i32, align 4
br label %17
store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
%20 = load i32, i32* %4, align 4
%21 = icmp sgt i32 %19, %20
```

Here I want to get save only the %1,%20,%21 IRs. How can this be done ?
For checking store IR , I used hasAtomicStore()
Is there any similar method for check Branch IR?

Comment: Like [isa<BranchInst>(i)](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Transforms/IPO/LoopExtractor.cpp#L110)?

Comment: Have you considered using `llvm::InstVisitor`: http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1InstVisitor.html? I think that's what you're looking for :)